# Tcl Expect spawn -open send_user - two different behaviors

Tags: tcl, expect

I am back to Tcl/Expect after a long time. It seems Expect isn't behaving the same for default `spawn_id` and explicit. AFAIK this wasn't the case.

I am using Expect 5.45 on Ubuntu. On an input file `input/input.found.txt` like:

```
~$ more input/input.found.txt
hello
World!
hello
<intentional blank new line>
```

Consider Expect code (use `send_user` or `puts`) where both cases differ only by `-i $file1` only:

```
package require Expect    
puts "---"

set file [open "input/input.found.txt" r]
spawn -open $file
set file1 $spawn_id
expect -i $file1 {
    -re ".ello" {
        send_user "found\r\n"; # should print BUT doesn't print
    }
    -re ".orld" {
        send_user "found the world!\r\n"; # shouldn't print, doesn't print
    }
    eof { puts "not found" }
}
exp_close $file1  
if {[info exists $file ] } {
    close $file
}

puts "---"

set file [open "input/input.found.txt" r]
spawn -open $file
set file1 $spawn_id
expect {
    -re ".ello" {
        send_user "found\r\n"; # should print, prints
    }
    -re ".orld" {
        send_user "found the world!\r\n"; # shouldn't print, doesn't print
    }
    eof { puts "not found" }
}
exp_close $file1
if {[info exists $file ] } {
    close $file
}

puts "---"
```

I expect outputs for both the cases to be the same but they aren't. The output I get is:

```
---
spawn [open ...]
hello
World!
hello

---
spawn [open ...]
hello
World!
hello

found
---
```

(Notice missing `found` in the first case.)

Where is my assumption about output wrong? Why explicit specification of `spawn_id` through `-i` (at least in file handling case) altering behavior of `send_user` or `puts`?

Comment: Have you tried running expect with verbose debugging turned on? I'm told that can help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your first expect command is not what you think. The expect command will take seperate arguments, or a single list of arguments.

Your first expect command has 3 arguments, so it takes the -i $file as an option specifying the spawn id and the last argument as a pattern without any body. That multi-line pattern doesn't match your file content. But even if it did, nothing would be printed as there is no body for that pattern.

Your second expect command has all arguments inside braces. The expect command then expands that list into 8 arguments.

The easiest fix for your program is to put the -i $file1 inside the braces, as in:

```
expect {
    -i $file1
    -re ".ello" {
        send_user "found\r\n"; # should print BUT doesn't print
    }
    -re ".orld" {
        send_user "found the world!\r\n"; # shouldn't print, doesn't print
    }
    eof { puts "not found" }
}
```